# jQuery traversing contiguos peers

Tags: jquery, traversal

I have a series of rows with different classes.

```
<tr class="head">...
<tr class="group">...
<tr class="item">...
<tr class="item">...
<tr class="item">...
<tr class="group">...
<tr class="item">...
<tr class="item">...
<tr class="item">...
<tr class="group">...
<tr class="item">...
<tr class="item">...
<tr class="item">...
```

Assuming my context is at one of the items, how do I select all the rows before, after and including it, that are items, without crossing over a group?

In this example, no matter what item row I am at, I should always result in a collection of three item rows.

Currently I have this, and while it works, I'm hoping there is a cleaner way.

```
var $itemRows = $targetRow.prevUntil('tr.group').add($targetRow.nextUntil('tr.group')).add($targetRow);
```

Something like `.siblings('tr.item')` but that will get all nine items, instead of the three contigous ones.  And I can't put these in tbodies, as this is already in a tbody and nesting them is invalid html.

I have improved it to

```
var $itemRows = $targetRow.prevAll('tr.group:first').nextUntil('tr.group');
```

Comment: If you can change the dom, I would just group them in distinct `tbody` elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `this` is one of the rows (and not a group), you could do this:

After testing out many scenarios, this is what I found worked:

```
$(this).prevUntil('tr.group').andSelf().nextUntil('tr.group').andSelf()
```

The issue is that when you click on the first item in a group, other combinations like gdoron's didn't work for me.

You can see this one work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/mks74/

---

I thought there must be a bit cleaner way, so I kept working on it and this is what I found:

```
$(this).prevAll('tr.group:first').nextUntil('tr.group')
```

You can see this one work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/HZVnX/

---

What would be useful here (which jQuery does not seem to provide) is a jQuery method that gets the prior sibling that meets some selector criteria.  We could make our own like this:

```
jQuery.fn.prior = function(selector) {
    return (this.pushStack(this.prevAll(selector).first()));
};
```

And, then the code to solve this issue becomes a little more logical to read:

```
$(this).prior('tr.group').nextUntil('tr.group')
```

Comment: Refined this to `$(this).prevAll('tr.group:first').nextUntil('tr.group');`

Comment: You should play with my fiddle, You code doesn't cover all the cases. http://jsfiddle.net/aH6Qu/

Comment: Works now in the jsFiddle I've test it in.

Comment: Added another option that's a little cleaner.